# Using Symbolize to Convert Multiple Variables at Once

Tags: symbolic, packages, variable, boxes

So, I have created a list of subscripted and overdotted variables that I would like to symbolize, so I run them through a for loop. Seems to me that this would work? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
Needs["Notation`"]
vars = {Subscript[v, t], Subscript[a, n], Subscript[a, t], 
    \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(.\)]\), Subscript[v, x], Subscript[v, y], 
    Subscript[v, o]}
For[i = 0, i = Length[vars], i++, Symbolize[vars[[i]]]
```

Comment: Wellcome! Please also provide the copiable form of the code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks!  Below is the end result.  After running this code, I can now use this custom notation as variable in the Mathematica notebook.  Also, just as a check, I used Head/@varlist to check that they are indeed recognized as symbols.

[image: Image of the code]

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize /@ {ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["v", "t"]], ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["a", "n"]], ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["a", "t"]], ParsedBoxWrapper[OverscriptBox["v", "."]], ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["v", "x"]], ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["v","y"]], ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["v","o"]]}; 
varlist = {Subscript[v, t], Subscript[a, n], Subscript[a, t],\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(.\)]\), Subscript[v, x], Subscript[v,  y], Subscript[v, o]}
Head /@ varlist
```

Comment: I think you should accept your answer as I realized mine not always works.

Answer (score 2):

@MGoforth, take a look at this presentation from the 2017 Wolfram Technology Conference. It covers advanced typesetting and the Notation package with lots of great examples.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJjqsFQZh2M&index=79&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx14H5wx-SbYKeH8uRap7adS