# Symbolized, Subscripted Variable Doesn't Look Pretty

Tags: front-end, symbols, custom-notation, boxes, subscript

## Background

I'm trying to programmatically generate a subscripted variable in a way that makes it appear "pretty". Here is a minimal working example that shows some strange behavior I'm trying to understand and correct for (picture of NB, code):

### Image of Code

[image: minimal-working-example]

### Copy-Pasted Code

```
(*fullform syntax*)
Subscript[s, 1] // FullForm

(*symbolize*)
<< Notation`
Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["s", "_"]]] // Once

(*recheck fullform syntax*)
Subscript[s, 2] // FullForm (*syntax has changed*)
s\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]2 (*pretty output*)
s\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]3 (*not pretty output*)
```

## Question

So, why does a symbolized, subscripted variable have to be input using "ctrl-_" and manually evaluated in order to look "pretty?

## Additional Comments

In the end, I'm hoping to generate a list of "pretty" subscripted variables and use this list while I'm doing derivations in higher dimensions, but it will only display pretty subscripted variables if I've previously evaluated them. Example:

```
n = 3; (*# of subscripted variables to generate*)
S = ToExpression[
   ToString[s\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]] <> 
    ToString[#]] & /@ Range[n] (*vector of subscripted variables, s2 is the only pretty output*)
```

## Related Questions

However, I really want to get this using the Symbolize[] functionality).

- [Creating a List of Symbolized Indexed Variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136013/creating-a-list-of-symbolized-indexed-variables)
- [Unexpected interpretation of a variable with subscripts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158447/unexpected-interpretation-of-a-variable-with-subscripts)
- [Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica)
- [Generating a list of symbolic coefficients [duplicate]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/generating-a-list-of-symbolic-coefficients)
- [Generating a vector of dummy variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/generating-a-vector-of-dummy-variables)
- [Using Symbolize to Convert Multiple Variables at Once](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180852/using-symbolize-to-convert-multiple-variables-at-once?rq=1)

Any discussion/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify a clear list of steps and the desired final result? I am having trouble understanding what is the final goal, what exactly did you do and in what order.

Comment: Hi @Kuba, sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question to try to clarify. I reference Mathematica Stack Exchange frequently, but am relatively new to questions, so let me know if you think it needs more revising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question the short answer is to produce your Symbols like this:

```
new = ToExpression[SubscriptBox["s", "3"]];

Head[new]

FullForm[new]
```

> ```
> Symbol
> ```

> ```
> s\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]3
> ```

The mechanism of the Notation package is to intercept [`MakeExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html) (called by [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html)) and [`MakeBoxes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html).  If these definitions do not trigger the package will not work.

The effect of your `Symbolize` command is a definition on `MakeExpression` (by way of `NotationMakeExpression`) that looks for a Box expression that matches `SubscriptBox["s", _]` and processes it accordingly.  When this processing takes place a rule is made on `MakeBoxes` (by way of `NotationMakeBoxes`) to handle the UnderBracket form.

If you are interested in these internal mechanisms have a look at:

```
DownValues[NotationMakeBoxes] // FullForm

DownValues[NotationMakeExpression] // FullForm
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you.

Comment: Not that it's a difficult extension of your answer but just as a reference for others, now I can very simply do: `n = 3; S = ToExpression[SubscriptBox["s", ToString[#]]]&/@Range[n]`